# redirect domain www links to www-staging on staging server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

So I KNOW this is doable with .htaccess, I just can't seem to get it working.

I have a staging server: `www-staging.mysite.com`

as well as a production server: `www.mysite.com`

I want to edit my `.htaccess` file so that, on my staging server, every request to `www.mysite.com` is changed to `www-staging.mysite.com`.

Every request on my production server should function as normal (`www.mysite.com`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the htaccess file of your staging server (in the document root), add this above any of the other rewrite rules (if there are any):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www-staging.mysite.com/$1 [L,R]
```

This only works if your staging and production servers are separate, with 2 different document roots.

Comment: thanks for the reply. This doesn't appear to be doing anything.. I've tried placing the .htaccess file both inside the doc root (www folder) as well as on the same level as the doc root.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place this rule in the `DocumentRoot/.htaccess` **of production server**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www-staging.mysite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=302]
```